# Commit changes from gitignore

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

On my branch under changes tracked there appears to be a .gitignore file with two changes that are now in there. How do I dissolve this file and put it with all other changes

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to stash the .gitignore file which will display the changes in file status